# What does unordered_map returns when looking for a key that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map<char, mystruct> h`.

What does this return if `h` doesn't contain a key `x`?

```
mystruct ms = h['x'];
```

Comment: Easy answer: Try it and find out! Second easiest: Read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: [I read but couldn't understand.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) It only says it adds if the value doesn't exist, but I didn't understand what it returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the specified key `'x'` doesn't exist, [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) will insert a value-initialized `mystruct` firstly, then return the reference to the inserted `mystruct`. After that `ms` is copy-initialized from the inserted `mystruct`.

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

> When the default allocator is used, this results in ... the mapped value being [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> **Return value**
> Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed.

Answer (score 2):

The unordered map will try to default initialize `mystruct` with the key `'x'` and assign to `mystruct`.

If you desire to avoid this, use `.at(key)`. If it doesn't exist, it will throw an `out_of_range` exception which you can catch and handle.

Answer (score 0):

if you directly use h['any key which is not present'] then it will give it some random value.
what you can do is whenever you're not sure about whether it is there or not just use it inside an if. if it is present it will return true and if not then false.
example: if(h['a'])cout<<h['a'];

Comment: *"it will give it some random value"* - this is not true - it gives a value-initialised `mystruct`, as songyuanyao says in his answer.  Which is why your `if (h['a']) cout << h['a];` suggestion is wrong too: that will add an element, then see if there's some way to evaluate `h['a']` in a boolean context - such an a `mystruct::operator bool() const` member function, if so then it will do the conversion and decide whether to print the value initialised object / if not it won't compile.